# NSPredicate with a boolean property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Supposed I have an object `Foo` with a boolean property `isLegit`, how do I write an NSPredicate in order to filter out the object where that property is set to `NO`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isLegit == NO)]
```